# Flutter throws FormatException error when JSON string is inputted correctly

Tags: json, flutter, dart, formatexception

Flutter is giving me this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 88586)
[        ] E/flutter ( 5286): ...820457458, -0.09168463200330734, 0.9341723918914795, 0.9910492897033691]}",
```

This is how I am inflating the list (that is later written to a JSON file):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <=32; ++i) {
            String entry = '{contents: ['
                '${contentList.content[i].x.toString()}, '
                '${contentList.content[i].y.toString()}, '
                '${contentList.content[i].z.toString()}, '
                '${contentList.content[i].visibility.toString()}, '
                '${contentList.content[i].presence.toString()}]}';
            content_collector.add(entry);
          }
```

`content_collector` is then passed to this function to write to a JSON file:

```
  Future<File> saveToJSONFile(List<String> contents_list, String filename) async {
    String encodedContents = jsonEncode(contents_list);
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + filename;

    return await File(appDocPath).writeAsString(encodedContents);
  }
```

and I have this function to read the generated JSON file:

```
void readJSON(String path) async {

    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + path;

    String response = await File(appDocPath).readAsString();
    final data = await json.decode(response.toString());

  }
```

So really, it is the `readJSON` function that throws this error.

Comment: You should in general not create JSON manually but instead use `jsonEncode`. But without the JSON you are trying to parse, it is hard to know fore sure what problem you have. One guess would be you have forgot to put `"` around `contents`.

Comment: @julemand101 I am using jsonEncode. This `entry` is sent to a function that invokes `jsonEncode` to turn it into JSON. The error says that there is soemthing wrong with my formatting.

Comment: Again. You should not create JSON manually which is clearly what you are doing here. Your method should just return a list of objects which each implement a `toJson()` method that tells how it should be encoded. But if you want to create JSON manually, you should ensure that `contents` is `"contents"`.

Comment: @julemand101 Can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you at least show an example of how you want your JSON to look like so I have something to base my example on?

Comment: @julemand101 check the edits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is not valid JSON

```
{contents: [
```

it should be

```
{"contents": [
```

Most likely the other parts needs to be surrounded with `"` as well

Answer (score 0):

As @julemand101 mentioned, this is not a proper approach, but also looking at the code, the string you are crating, is not being concatenated either. Try this:

```
 String entry = "{'contents': [
                '${contentList.content[i].x.toString()}', 
                '${contentList.content[i].y.toString()}',
                '${contentList.content[i].z.toString()}',
                '${contentList.content[i].visibility.toString()}',
                '${contentList.content[i].presence.toString()}'
               ]}";
```